# How to dismiss flutter dismissable widget programmatically?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Is it possible to dismiss dismissable programmatically? Not by swipe, but by let's say button click.
 The only thing that comes in mind is imitating gesture event with a certain velocity, but this sounds horribly wrong.

Comment: Hi! Did you do this?

Comment: @andreich used the AnimatedList as a workaround

Answer (score 2):

How about considering an [AnimatedList](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AnimatedList-class.html) instead.

> A scrolling container that animates items when they are inserted or removed.
>   This widget is similar to one created by ListView.builder.

Comment: That's the way I got my feature to work at the time, but that's a bit different. So question remains unanswered @Jannie.

Comment: With an AnimatedList that animates out an item, the items below suddenly jump up to replace the empty space. A dismissible however makes the items below gradually go up

Comment: @WouterVandenputte for item not to jump up - you have to set AnimatedListState.removeItem.builder property. It is called _buildRemovedItem in this example: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AnimatedList-class.html#widgets.AnimatedList.1

Answer (score -2):

Please try this.

```
key: Key(UniqueKey().toString()),
```

**2nd Way**

```
onDismissed: (DismissDirection direction) { dismissViewList(ObjecClass); }
```

And function is :

```
dismissViewList(ObjecClass) {
    if (_personList.contains(ObjecClass)) {
    //_personList is list of ObjecClass shown in ListView
      setState(() {
        _personList.remove(ObjecClass);
      });
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry, but this is not an answer. ListView is not used, + key does not allow to invoke any actions on the widget.